# PowerShell - Select only a portion of returned property

Tags: powershell, exchange-server

Can anyone give me a quick tip on how to return only a portion of a property from the following cmdlet?

```
get-mobiledevice | select UserDisplayName,DeviceType,DeviceModel
```

The UserDisplayName property comes back as..
domain.local/OU Name/OU Name/First Last

I only want to return "Frist Last" and strip out the full domain and OU path.

Regards,
Adam Tyler

Comment: There's a couple of ways you can do this but, one that would be easier to understand is using the `-split` operator. Say you assign the return value to a variable like so: `$Var = Get-MobileDevice`. You can the use the operator to split the return of just that one property like so: `$Var.UserDisplayName.Split('/')[3]` and it'll grab the last value referencing it's correct index location/number.

Comment: Thanks @AbrahamZinala, I have used split before and I think it would work...  Sort of.  Issue 1 with this is, what happens when I have a varying count of forward slash characters.  A regex string of some kind to capture anything after the last forward slash would be cool as an alternative.  Issue 2 with this is getting the value in line with the other properties.  I was hoping to craft a custom property including the regex string right in the same command.

Comment: Wasn't sure if you wanted to take on Regex sinc it's a bit intimidating. You can use the following `$Var.UserDisplayName -Replace '.*/'` this will get you only that last part after the last slash of any expression following that standard.

Comment: Sweet, seems like that strips everything out up to and including the last forward slash.  Now, wonder how difficult it would be to do this in line with the initial command?  Sort of like this: https://learn.microsoft.com/bs-latn-ba/powershell/scripting/samples/selecting-parts-of-objects--select-object-?view=powershell-5.1

Comment: Wait, I think I got it.
`get-mobiledevice | select DeviceID,FriendlyName, @{
label='DoctoredName'
expression={$_UserDisplayName -replace ".*/"}
}`

Comment: Hey, sorry for the late response! It would be done like so: `get-mobiledevice | select DeviceType,DeviceModel, @{Name='User Name';Expression={$_.UserDisplayName  -replace '.*/'}}`

Comment: Yes, just like you did it as long as you dot notate the correct property.

Comment: Could also still be done using the `-split` operator: `get-mobiledevice | select DeviceType,DeviceModel, @{Name='User Name';Expression={$_.UserDisplayName .Split('/')[-1]}}`. Using `[-1]` will grab you the last value after the split.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala you want to post your latest suggestion and I'll mark as answer.
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1):

This is what I personally use when I need to split a `canonicalName`:

```
$canonical='domain.local/OU Name/OU Name/First Last'
Split-Path $canonical -Leaf

# This also works:
$canonical.Substring($canonical.LastIndexOf('/')+1)
```

In your example, the code should look like this:

```
# This:
$expression={
    Split-Path $_.UserDisplayName -Leaf
}

# Or This:
$expression={
    $_.UserDisplayName.Substring($_.UserDisplayName.LastIndexOf('/')+1)
}

Get-MobileDevice | select @{n='UserDisplayName';e=$expression},DeviceType,DeviceModel
```

Comment: Used the same attribute to accomplish this! Lol